# Progressbar Windows 10 - Slow UI Update?

Tags: winforms, windows-10, progress-bar

I have an application that is running under windows 7 and windows 10 machines.

A very simple "method" is transfering some files during startup, therefore a progressbar displays a progress (0-100%), while checking the file in question (change-date) if it needs to be copied again.

With Windows 7, everything works as expected. Basically it's just a foreach, comparing dates, then copying or not.

```
for (i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
   {
      copyOrNot(files[i]);
      progress = ((Double)i + 1) / (Double)fileCount;
      this.progressBar_Loading.Value = Convert.ToInt16(progress);
      Application.DoEvents();
   }
```

Using the application with Windows 7, the progressbar runs perfectly fine upto 100%, no matter if files are copied or not.

With Windows 10, I noted, that the UI-Update of the progressbar is "damn slow" - If out of 20 files none needs to be copied, the Progressbar shows 50% at maximum, then the whole process is finished and the application starts.

While (technically) there is no difference, it would be "nice", if Windows 10 could display the correct progress even if no (time-consuming) copy is required.

Adding "Thread.Sleeps" after each file fixes the issue for Windows 10 - but I don't want to slow down the process artificially just to have a proper UI-Output on Windows 10.

Any recommendations?

ps.: During the "Splash-Screen", everything happens on the UI-Thread, hence the `Application.DoEvents()`.

pps.: Even though the "Status-Label" reporting the status says "100%" - the Progressbar under Windows 10 just proceeded to about 50%)

edit:

Example, Windows 10 (With Windows 7, the progressbar would already hit the "End" of the bar - calculation repots 100%, UI doesn't.)

[image]

Windows 7:

[image]

Edit: I've now moved all the timeconsuming stuff into its own thread, using delegates to update the ui - still the same problem.

Only adding a "Thread.sleep" of about 250ms at the end of the thread allows the UI to proper show 100% on the progressbar under windows 10...

Comment: Try using `this.progressBar_Loading.Refresh()` instead of the `Application.DoEvents()` method call.  Also, the ProgressBar.Value property is an Int32, so why the `Convert.ToInt16` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`?

Comment: @TnTinMn Tested it, no change...

Comment: We would have to see the new code.